# How to show $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

How to show that $\sqrt{p}$ is an irrational number, given that $p$ is a prime number?

$\sqrt{p}=\frac{a}{b}$

$p=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$

Comment: Do you know how to prove it for $p=2$? For a general prime it is exactly the same proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\sqrt p=\frac{a}{b}$ with $(a,b)=1$.

Then 
\begin{align*}
b^2p=a^2&\implies p\mid a^2\\
 &\implies p\mid a\\
&\implies \exists k\in\mathbb Z: a=kp\\
&\implies b^2p=k^2p^2\\
&\implies pk^2=b^2\\
&\implies p\mid b^2\\
&\implies p\mid b.
\end{align*} 
Since $(a,b)=1$, we get $p=1$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ have no common factors, i.e., the fraction is in its lowest form.
$$a^2 = pb^2 \implies p | a^2 \implies p | a  \implies a = pa_1 \implies p^2a_1^2 = pb^2 \implies pa_1^2 = b^2 \implies p | b^2 \implies p|b$$

This implies $a$ and $b$ have $p$ as a common factor which contradicts what we assumed without loss of generality.